# JavaScript variable in a href

Tags: javascript, html

sorry for the basic question, but I can't seem to get this to work, I have some javascript code, and I want to include a variable in place of a hyperlink:

```
var list = "<dl><dt>Bini</dt>"
    + "<dd>" + feature.properties.name + "</dd>"
    + "<dd>" + feature.properties.description + "</dd>"
    + "<dt><a href=" + myHyperlink + "</a></dt>"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `myHyperlink`? Are you getting an errors?

Comment: You are not closing the opening `<a>` tag.

Comment: and you forgot the quotes around the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you aren't closing the open anchor.
2. The href value needs to have quotes around it.
3. You don't have text around the anchor.
4. Don't forget the semicolon.

   `` var list = "<dl><dt>Bini</dt>"
       + "<dd>" + feature.properties.name + "</dd>"
       + "<dd>" + feature.properties.description + "`</dd>"
       + "<dt><a href='" + myHyperlink + "'>Click me!</a></dt>"; ``